# Solving Equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following equations. I'll solve the system of equations and x and y must be integers.

```
x+yz=2016
xy+z=2015
```

I saw by looking at the equations that y=0, x=2016 and z=2015 is the answer. 
But I can not prove it. How do I prove it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not concern the technical computing software *Mathematica*.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: why do you think demonstrating a solution found by  observation is not a valid proof?

Comment: @george2079 showing that the solution is unique (in the non-negative integers) requires a little more than observation (I think)

Comment: well if he wanted to proove uniqueness he should have said so. I wouldn't quite accept the `Reduce` result as "proof" btw, more like strong evidence.

Answer (score 2):

```
Reduce[{x + y z == 2016, x y + z == 2015, x >= 0, y >= 0, 
  z >= 0}, {x, y, z}, Integers]
(* y == 0 && x == 2016 && z == 2015 *)
```